# PHP Code Session Not Working

Tags: php

My PHP code dosnt seem to be working and I dont Know Why when Ever I Use this code it will Make The whole webpage appear white.I think the problem is Here Somewhere`echo Hello, (.$_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`Thanks In Advance

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
  echo '<a href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}

else {
  echo Hello, (.$_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
  echo '</br></b>';
  echo  '<a href="/user-area/logout.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}
```

Comment: try adding quotes around `Hello`?

Comment: You have a syntax error at `echo Hello(.`. A white screen in PHP means go check your error log. Enable error reporting, and display_errors always when developing code. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You need to concatenate the string `"Hello, "` with the session variable.  `echo "Hello, " . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION...`  It looks like you also lost part of a call to `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 3):

When your page goes white, it usually means you have a fatal error in your code and need to check your logs, or turn on `error_reporting`.

In this case you're missing quotes, have the concatenation a bit messed up, and appear to be missing a function call (probably `htmlspecialchars`).

Also, you're checking `$_SESSION['user']` a few lines before in your code, are you sure you don't mean to echo that here instead of `$_SESSION['username']`?

I think you want to change that line to:

```
echo "Hello, " . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: `($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` is not valid PHP.  It's probably missing `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks, not sure how I missed that. Updated answer

Comment: Right, It's Now displaying the page again But Its not not displaying the Username.

Comment: @user2925945 Well that just sounds like `$_SESSION['username']` is empty. Are you sure you don't mean to do `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: Ok I have just Tried that and  unfortunately its the same

Comment: @user2925945 If you're echoing a variable and getting nothing, then the variable is empty. What are you looking for us to do about that?

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['user']))` is excessive. Change that to just `if(empty($_SESSION['user']))`

Comment: I have Been Using This Code and it works really well but i cant get it to work with the code above <b>Hello,  <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b>

Comment: Wait so now it's `$_SESSION['user']['username']`? That's not what you posted in your question. Your code keeps changing. Do `print_r($_SESSION['user'])` to see what you actually have in your session 'user' array. I think you don't have it set. It's not a problem with your echo code.

Comment: No That's Another Code That Has been working for me

Comment: Look at your session. `print_r($_SESSION)`. Make sure your data is actually present. I can't help you troubleshoot stuff that I can't see. Your original question has already been answered, if you have a different question then please post a new question, not do it in the comments.